# Powershell batch export/convert Excel to TXT (unicode)

Tags: excel, powershell

The goal is to convert all xls files in a directory (with subfolders) to txt (unicode), saving txt in the same locations with same names as original xls files.
I have it like this, not working:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem D:\test\*.xls -recurse
Write "Loading Files..."

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files)
{
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilepath = $file.Fullname -replace ".{4}$"
     $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".txt"
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,42)   
}
  Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
  $Excel.Quit()
```

It gives en exception:

```
No access to 'FileName.txt'.
At line:13 char:6
+      $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,42)
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to also release the `$WorkBook` object.. Edited my answer to also do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with the way you kill the Excel process before quitting it.
Try this way:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem D:\test\*.xls -recurse

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files) {
     Write "Loading File '$($file.Name)'..."
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".txt")
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 42)   # xlUnicodeText
}

# cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

As you can see, I have also changed the method of creating a new filename by using the `[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()`method. This will make it easier if at one point you have to deal with `.xlsx` files.

Also, always **release ComObjects** after use (the four lines at the bottom will take care of that)